Does pulling a recoil rope when small engine is rotating cause any damage?
Recently, I accidentally released the pull rope of my lawnmower after succesfully starting it. The spring caused it to go past the handle rest on the handlebars, so the pull rope crashed against the engine casing. Then I pulled the pull rope very slowly towards me so that I can place it on the handle rest on the handlebars, with the engine rotating. I heard metal-to-metal sounds from the lawnmower engine when pulling the rope with the engine rotating, which could indicate that something may have been damaged.
Fortunately, nothing seems to be damaged. I can stop and restart the engine just fine.
I understand that the engine has a freewheel clutch, so pulling the starter rope slowly with the engine rotating should cause no damage, since the engine side of the freewheel clutch is anyway rotating faster than I pull the rope. But if it causes no damage, how is it possible that I heard the metal-on-metal sounds from it?
What effects does pulling the starter rope with engine rotating have? What is the sound I heard from the engine and what's causing it? Is it possible to damage something in the engine if this is done repeatedly?
The sounds were so bad that next time if I accidentally let go of the rope with spring pulling it past the handle rest, I'll shut down the engine, pull the rope slowly to its rest, then restart the engine.

No damage and no worries.
Maybe you live where there's not much snow? Snowblowers use the same kind of pull starter mechanism and their manuals usually recommend that before you shut down the snowblower when used in active snowy conditions, always give a few yanks on the starter rope with the engine running to clear out any accumulated snow or slush from the mechanism. This prevents the mechanism from freezing up when it cools down.
It makes a clacking, clattering sound when you do this but it doesn't cause any harm. (If it did, the manufacturer wouldn't recommend it and cause more warranty claims.)
There's a mechanism with a spring-loaded pawl inside the pull-start hub which keeps the pawl(s) retracted when you're not pulling the rope. You can usually pop the hub off by removing some screws, so feel free to look inside and see how it works if you wish.
And if not, just relax -- no harm done!
